# Why is this IO operation looping infinitely?

Tags: c++, ifstream, strtok, atoi

I am trying to read from a text file and tokenize the input. I was getting a segmentation fault until I realized I forgot to close my ifstream. I added the close call and now it loops infinitely. I'm just trying to learn how to use strtok for now, that is why the code doesn't really look complete.

```
void loadInstructions(char* fileName)
{
   ifstream input;
   input.open(fileName);
   while(!input.eof());
   {
      string line; 
      getline (input,line);
      char * lineChar = &line[0];
      //instruction cmd; //This will be used later to store instructions from the parse
      char * token;
      token = strtok (lineChar," "); 
      // just trying to get the line number for now
      int lineNumber = atoi(token);
      cout << lineNumber << "\n";
   }
   input.close();
}
```

input file:(one line)

`5 +8 0 0 25`

Comment: Calling `close` does absolutely nothing as it's implicitly called upon the `ifstream`'s destruction at the end of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `while(input.good());` is probably not what you intended...

Comment: here is where it causes infinity loop.

Comment: Just to be pedantic (i.e. since @Eugen didn't actually spell it out), the semicolon at the end of the quoted line is the problem - get rid of it! +1

Comment: Lol! I must have got in a hurry. I did learn that strtok is bad so I guess this wasn't a complete waste of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
string line; 
while(getline (input,line))
{
```

If the getline() works then the loop is entered.
If you try and read past the EOF then it will fail and the loop will exit.

So this should word as expected.

Rather than using strtok() (which damages the string) and atoi() which is non portable.
Use std::stringstream

```
    std::stringstream  linestream(line);

    int lineNumber;
    linestream >> lineNumber; // reads a number from the line.
```

Don't explicitly close() the stream (unless you want to detect and correct for any problems). The file will be closed when the object goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: I recommend this way, i always use it too.

Comment: stringstream linestream(line) throws the following compile error:std stringstream linestream has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: You need `#include <sstream>`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `eof()` not `good()`.

Comment: Don't do that either. You will end up reading an extra phantom line.

Comment: Sorry, I will pay a bit attention next time, it is indeed eof.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `strtok`. There are other ways to tokenize a string that do not require the called function to modify your string. The fact that it modifies the string it tokenizes could also be what causes the loop here.

But more likely, the `good()` member is not the right one. Try `!input.eof()` or similar, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

While you've already gotten some answers to the question you asked, perhaps it's worth answering some you *should* have about the code that you didn't ask:

```
void loadInstructions(char* fileName)
```

Since the function isn't going to modify the file name, you almost certainly want to change this to:

```
void loadInstructions(char const *fileName)
```

or

```
void loadInstructions(std::string const &fileName)
```

---

```
ifstream input;
input.open(fileName);
```

It's much cleaner to combine these:

```
ifstream input(fileName);
```

or (if you passed a string instead):

```
ifstream input(fileName.c_str());
```

---

```
while(!input.eof());
```

This has already been covered.

```
  string line; 
  getline (input,line);
  char * lineChar = &line[0];
  //instruction cmd; //This will be used later to store instructions from the parse
  char * token;
  token = strtok (lineChar," "); 
  // just trying to get the line number for now
  int lineNumber = atoi(token);
```

Most of this is just extraneous. You can just let `atoi` convert directly from the original input:

```
string line;
getline(input, line);
int lineNumber = atoi(line);
```

If you're going to tokenize more later, you can use `strtol` instead:

```
char *end_ptr;
int lineNumber = strtol(line, &end_ptr, 10);
```

This will set `end_ptr` to point just past the end of the part that `strtol` converted.

I'd also consider an alternative though: moving your code for reading and parsing a line into a class, and define `operator>>` to read those:

```
struct line { 
    int number;
    operator int() { return number; }
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, line &l) {
// Just for fun, we'll read the data in an alternative fashion.
// Instead of read a line into a buffer, then parse out the first number,
// we'll read a number from the stream, then ignore the rest of the line.
// I usually prefer the other way, but this is worth knowing as well.

    is >> l.number;

    // When you're ready to parse more, add the extra parsing code here.

    is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::istream::pos_type>::max, '\n');
    return is;
}
```

With this in place, we can print out the line numbers pretty easily:

```
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<line>(input),
          std::istream_iterator<line>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

---

```
input.close();
```

I'd usually just let the stream close automatically when it goes out of scope.